# Java EE development environment?

Tags: jakarta-ee

I'm starting a jJava EEee project and I was trying to see if it's beneficial (and how to) setup a local Java EE server to test on, much like the .net development server runs.

I have a development spot in our enterprise development server, which is where I'll do most of my testing, but I was just curious if there was any benefit to having a local running copy for debugging or other such uses.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Oh yes, local dev environment is way to go.  Especially with eclipse, since it can hot deploy your code.

Comment: Yep. Definitely. Use your own Java EE appserver.

Comment: Use Netbeans, and you can profile your local appserver.  Profiling could work in eclipse but TPTP is very hard to get to work.

Comment: oh just to add, whether local or not, for debugging - log4j is indispensable :)

Answer (score 1):

check also http://zeroturnaround.com/jrebel/ it allow to work without redeploying.